# How to call WCF as a object parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I tried to connect to an API through WCF service. I was successful if I pass the values as many parameters, but when I tried to pass all the parameters to a created class I can't. How can I call it using jQuery Post method?

My attendenceService.cs file

```
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "/mobileAttendance")]
List<Attendance.attendenceService.ResultClass> applyMobileAttendance(Attendance.attendenceService.MobileAttendance attObj);
```

My attendenceService.svc.cs file

```
public List<Attendance.attendenceService.ResultClass> applyMobileAttendance(Attendance.attendenceService.MobileAttendance attObj)
    {
    ....
    ....
    }


//Attendance.attendenceService.MobileAttendance
        [DataContract]
        [Serializable]
        public class MobileAttendance
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int companyID { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int employeeID { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int checkType { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string timeEntry { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string longitude { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string latitude { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string location { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string locationImage { get; set; }
        }
```

I tried to call it using below method:

```
$.post("http://localhost:1915/attendenceService.svc/mobileAttendance", "{companyID:'12',employeeID:'15',checkType:'25',timeEntry:'1232',longitude:'efef',latitude:'fgdg',location:'1424',locationImage:'fdgdfg'}", function (result,status) {
            alert("success");
        });
```

Comment: Can you post your Contract code also?

Comment: @Hameed Al ready I posted above, I think the parameter format is wrong
"{companyID:'12',employeeID:'15',checkType:'25',timeEntry:'1232',longitude:'efef',latitude:'fgdg',location:'1424',locationImage:'fdgdfg'}" please help me.

Comment: I meant service contract, let's see how you are passing the parameters

Comment: @Hameed [OperationContract]